# Command not found when using git commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-for-windows

**EDIT: It's solved! Thanks :)**

I'm using Windows 10 OS and trying to learn git through Git Bash. But the commit command isn't working. I'm new to git and learning it from Youtube tutorials.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Looks like you don't have your editor set up properly. Pass the commit message directly from the command line for now until you can sort it out, e.g. `git commit -m "My first commit"`.

Comment: try `git commit -m "your commit message"`

Comment: You seems to have selected VScode as your message editor, but "code" is not accessible from PATH, you should check it if is properly installed, or provide full path to it in configuration

Comment: I believe I'm using Sublime Text as my text editor, cause I remember learning a bit from Udacity and using the following codes:

Comment: git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"

Comment: also, I don't have Visual Studio Code installed